# Spring Websocket with SockJs switch from XHR streaming to Websocket

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using Spring Websocket with SockJs (v1.1.1) over STOMP on client. I create the client with the code below.

```
SockJS = require('sockjs-client')
Stomp = require('webstomp-client')
stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url))
```

It's works fine. But it uses `xhr_streaming` as transport by default, that is not desirable for me. I want to switch it to `websocket` tranport.

```
stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS(url, null, {transports:'websocket'}))
```

But this approach does not work for me. It falls with event:

```
code: 2000
reason: "All transports failed"
```

My Spring Websocket configuration is very simple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<ExpiringSession> {

    @Override
    public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/myEndpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

}
```

The main problem I face with `xhr_streaming` is that every stream request updates last access time for user session (I use Spring Session as well). But it's not a desirable behavior for my application. So how I can fix it? And will `websocket` transport help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

So, I've got the reason. I am using a webpack dev server with `proxy` option. By default it does NOT proxy `ws` protocol requests (it losts headers). You need toa add `ws: true` to your config and everything will work fine.

```
proxy: {
        '/api/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''},
            ws: true 
        }
    }
```